# Windows 11 Pro keeps getting Blue Screens, volmgr.sys seems related to the issue

Tags: bsod, windows-11

**Background info**

my Laptop started getting random Bluescreens on 31. August. The Blue screens seemed to appear randomly without any specific activity beforehand. However due to reallife reasons I also didnt have any internet connection starting on the same day. The Bluescreens would sometimes appear just minutes after turning the device on, sometimes only after 1-2 hours of running it. On 02. September I finally got internet connection again and the bluescreens suddenly disappeared. Back then I thought it might have been a Windows update that stopped mid-updating and caused errors or something. After my internet returned my laptop downloaded some updates and the bluescreens stopped.
However yesterday evening the bluescreens started to appear again. I checked the Windows Update history and there were 3 Windows Updates prior to the bluescreen, however this might also just be a coincidence. I never had any problems or bluescreens with my laptop prior to the 31. August.

**PC Specs:**

- Intel Core i9-11900H
- Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080 running at 165W
- 32GB DDR4 Ram 3200Mhz
- Windows 11 Pro

**Error Description**

It will first get a bluescreen which just states that a "CRITICAL_PROCCESS_DIED". The bluescreen will Stay for a while and then disappear, the laptop will then open the Bios. Leaving the Bios doesnt work, everytime I try to manually exit the Bios the Bios will just instantly open up again. So I have to shut the Laptop down with the power button.
After the restart there will be 3 events saved in the event viewer. (in order of appearance)

- Error: Event ID 161, Source volmgr, Dump file creation failed due to error during dump creation.
- Critical: Event ID 41, Source Kernel-Power, The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
- Warning: Event ID 219, Source Kernel-PnP, The driver \Driver\WudfRd failed to load for the device ROOT\WINDOWSHELLOFACESOFTWAREDRIVER\0000.

**Already tried**

- I removed 2 of the 3 Windows updates that my Laptop did yesterday, It doesnt let me remove the third one
- I ran "sfc /scannow" in the command prompt - no problems found
- I ran "chkdsk C: /F" in the command prompt - no problems found
- I ran "dism /online /cleanup-iamge /resorehealth" in the command prompt - finished succesfully
- I used the Driver verifier manager to stresstest every single driver, no problems found
- I updated every driver on my device

None of this helped, the bluescreens keep appearing randomly. I did some research and there are tons of results when googling "volmgr.sys blue screen", it seems to bea common problem, and volmgr does in fact seem to be related to the bluescreens. However none of the mentioned methods from the internet to resolve this problem works on my device.

Comment: The blue screens you describe are not a problem of Windows 11 and do not occur on my Windows 11 machines. Use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App and update ALL drivers including BIOS.  Then get Nirsoft's Blue Screen View and examine a dump file.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not create a memory dump. I checked the settings and its set to automatically create a memory dump when encountering a bluescreen, however it doesnt do that. Maybe this has something to do with the first mentioned logged event which says "Dump file creation failed due to error during dump creation."

Comment: Try also the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App.

Comment: When you say "manufacturer" do you mean microsoft/windows or the company that the Laptop is from? Its a Medion Erazer Beast, and the only non standard software that was installed is the Medion Control Center which does not have any diagnostic capabilites.

Comment: I mean the manufacturer of the laptop.  They should have such an app.

Comment: Your issue is fairly serious and if it is not a driver issue or (less likely) a hardware issue, then you are likely faced with reinstalling Windows. Run the PC Health Check (Microsoft) to see if it uncovers computer issues that affect Windows 11.

Comment: Im sorry, my bad. I finally found the manufacturers diagnostic&repair tool. Those diagnostics are taking a long time,  will run them now. I will also run the microsoft pc health check as suggested by you. I would realy like to not have to reinstall windows, but I will if everything else fails. Thank you so far, I will report back later when all the diagnostics&repairs are done.

Comment: I did run all the diagnostics/repairs/driver updates from the manufacturer, however it did not have the option to do a Bios update.
This might just be a coincidence, but I did not have a bluescreen this whole day, usually I would have had at least 2 or 3 at this point, so maybe this fixed my problem, however it didnt show me a Log of what exactly it did or fixed so im not sure.

Comment: Please let me know if you are happy with my suggestions and if so I will post an answer

Comment: yes sure, post the answer , thank you :)

Comment: I have posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is fairly serious and the blue screens you describe are not a problem of Windows 11 and do not occur on my Windows 11 machines.

I suggest that you use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App and update ALL drivers including BIOS if it offers a BIOS update.

If the Blue Screen produces a dump file in the mninidump folder, then get Nirsoft's Blue Screen View and examine a dump file. –

I also run the PC Health Check (Microsoft) to see if it uncovers computer issues that affect Windows 11. This is an optional step.

Answer (score 0):

Error 161(Volmgr) is most (actually... ALL I've seen) physical related cases, usually involving storage, it's something you'll never find the solution in the system

See if the SATA is 100% seated, see if it is clean, see if there is nothing wrongly seated, clean with a brush, test another SSD/HD is definitive to understand, also change the SATA cable if you use it

usually the error occurs when playing, some cases using normally (these cases usually give CRITICAL_PROCCESS_DIED)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I checked every hardware connection and didnt find any problems there, everything seems to be properly seated/connected.
Also, you are saying that it usually occurs while playing, however for me it didnt show any tendency for a specific situation, it happens when browsing the web, when typing text, when programming, when gaming and even while im not on the laptop at all and the Laptop just being in locked screen not doing anything.